# Learning unknown independent sets of variables

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, references, independence, graphical-model

Let $(X_{j})_{j\in S}$
be random variables where $S=A\cup B$, $A\cap B=\emptyset$ and
$$
P(X_1,\ldots,X_{|S|})
=P(X_A)P(X_B).
$$

Given $n$ iid samples, the problem is to learn $A$ and $B$, which are unknown. This seems like a simple enough problem that it should be studied somewhere in the statistics literature, but I've come up short so far.

*Edit.* There is an obvious brute-force algorithm (test all subsets), but of course my question is about either existing estimators that improve upon this or other related references. Obviously, in order to derive nontrivial estimators, we need to place assumptions on $P$. Even in the simplest case of a multivariate Gaussian, I am not aware of any methods.

Comment: I wonder what the "obvious brute-force algorithm" might possibly be, because in this general setting, with no distributional assumptions, it is difficult enough to test independence of just two (scalar) variables.  I *assume* this is what you are doing--your notation is too vague to be sure.  If this assumption is incorrect, could you explain what you mean by "$P(X_A)P(X_B)$"?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, @whuber; I edited my post to clarify this. Obviously some type of regularity condition such as smoothness or a parametric model is needed. In these settings independence testing is well-understood.